# Get File from POST request body NodeJS & Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am working on an MEAN Stack application and I am trying to manage a form that allows users to upload a file when they submit. It appears to be working on the client side, however when I send the post request from the client and inspect the request body the file is an empty object. It is just a small .docx file so it should be fine size-wise. But I do not understand why nothing is properly received since the request goes through with out error. I was under the impression that files could be sent this way.

Am I missing something?

code from angular service

```
  sendApplcation(data : any): Observable <any>
  {
    return this.http.post(this.url+ '/careers/api/application', data);
  }
```

nodejs code

```
router.post("/api/application", (req, res) => {
  const application = req.body;
  console.log(req.body.file);
  let email = {
    to: `${req.body.email}`,
    from: "Careers@TrueLogistics.ca",
    subject: "Application Recieved",
    text: JSON.stringify(req.body),
    html: `<p> ${JSON.stringify(req.body)} </p>`,
  };
  mailer.sendMail(email, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  email.to = "mjayfalconi@gmail.com";
  mailer.sendMail(email, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  res.json("Applcation Submitted Successfully!");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `multer` package on npm.

File upload works a bit differently than the normal request.

You will also set `enctype` to `multipart` at the front end.

Furthermore, I see you are using `nodemailer` to send the file as an attachement. Read the documentation about the attachment. You don't send the file that way.

```js
//Dependencies 
const multer = require('multer');

 //Multer DiskStorage Config 
const diskStorage = multer.diskStorage(
{ destination: 'assets/profile_upload'} );

 //Create Multer Instance
 const upload = multer({ storage: diskStorage });

 //File upload 
//or app.post()

 router.post('/upload-file', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => { 

//The file 
 console.log(req.file)
;});

//Your code: 
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => { ... try doing app.post('/upload' ,upload.single('file'),
```

Also check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61341352/9662626

Sorry for the bad formatting. I only have access to my phone at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I know about sending the file as an attachment but right now I want to make sure I can receive it  first.  I will try changing the enctype thanks

Comment: Just wondering So it is basically working with 1 exception, when the file is uploaded it doesn't contain the extension, when i read it back I think its in binary, do you know how to retain the original file format so when I send as an attachment its still a .docx

Comment: Is it always going to be .docx or it might change?

Comment: I have limited it to .docx  and .pdf I just want to retain the same file type as is uploaded

Comment: I use the code above for uploading pictures, and it always keep the extension.  Can you console log req.file can check the oriifmalname property of the request object? What does it say?

Comment: {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'Reflection for BCI433.docx',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: '261af4ead2a5a70459dc3b71ba473386',
  path: 'uploads\\261af4ead2a5a70459dc3b71ba473386',

Comment: It seems like that it's keeping the original name. What does the file look like if you check the actual upload directory?

Comment: d0d732961c91b6efff5f0ad78d257f3b

Comment: ah I got it! dude you are literally the best thank you soo much!

Comment: I just changed the code in the answer. So you'll have to remove the `filename' option when you're trying to create the multer disk storage

Comment: Ah if it works too then it good. Thank you for your complement man.

Comment: haha np thank you I honestly don't know if i would have figured this out :P

Comment: That's why we have stack overflow